# Need help getting results printed correctly in nested while loops with PDO statements

Tags: php, mysql

I have two SQL queries. The first pulls a list of users and then the second pulls a sales report. After the report is pulled, I want to generate a PDF for each employee based on their sales. The problem is that I can't get the nested while loop to print more than only 1 record for the employee before going onto the next employee. I tried referencing userid's, but it just prints all of the lines to the first userid in the array then. If someone could tell me what I am missing, I would GREATLY appreciate it... I have been staring at this for like five hours today.

```
$stmt2 = $con->prepare("select user_id from users");
$stmt2->execute();

$stmt = $con->prepare("select u.user_id, u.fname, u.lname, d.saledate, d.custname, d.straddr, d.city, d.state, d.zip
from users u
inner join dplgalionsales d
on u.lname = d.agent_last_name
where saledate > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)");
$stmt->execute();

while($usrid = $stmt2->fetch()) {
    $uid = $usrid['user_id'];
    $mydate = date('m/d/Y');
    $dateadd = date('m/d/Y', strtotime($mydate. ' + 3 days'));  
    $html_table = '<div>Week Ending: ' .$mydate. '<br>Payroll Issued: ' .$dateadd. '</div><br>';
    $html_table .= '<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="100%"><tr><th>Date</th><th>Customer Name</th><th>Address</th></tr>';
    while($result = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $resuser = $result['user_id'];
        if($resuser = $uid) {
            $html_table .= '<tr><td>' .$result['saledate']. '</td><td>' .$result['custname']. '</td><td>' .$result['straddr']. ' ' .$result['city']. ' ' .$result['state']. ' ' .$result['zip']. '</td></tr>';
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    $html_table .= '</table>'; //ends HTML table
    $mpdf = new mPDF();
    $mpdf->SetTitle('DPL Galion Sales');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html_table);
    $mpdf->Output('./reports/'.$uid.'/'.date('m-d-Y').'_SalesID_'.$uid.'.pdf','F');
}

exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line is incorrect:

```
if($resuser = $uid)
```

For comparison it should be `==` or `===`

Also try to combine this query into a single one if possible

Comment: Now it only writes the start of the PDF header to the PDF document and doesn't write any of the sales results.